# Using jQuery to select from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have an array of HTML elements that looks like this...

```
var info = [<tr>...</tr>, <tr class="name">...</tr>, <tr class="colour">...</tr>]
```

If I only want to select the class `name` from the array `info`, how can I do this with jQuery? I expected something like the following to work:

```
$([info, '.name:first']);
```

But it didn't. Am I getting some minor detail wrong here or can you simply not select from arrays with jQuery?

Comment: `$(info).filter(".name:first")`?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work in Chrome's Dev Tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second argument of `jQuery`:

```
var filtered = $('.name:first', info);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var filtered = $(info).find('.name:first');
```

If the selector needs to find top level elements, as stored in the array, then use filter:

```
var filtered = $(info).filter('.name:first')
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Brilliant! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the contents of the Array are genuine element nodes, then it would be easier to simply use `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Element.matches()`:

```js
var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')),
    test = items.filter(row => row.matches('tr.test'));
console.log(test);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="colour"></tr>
    <tr class="colour"></tr>
    <tr class="colour"></tr>
    <tr class="test"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above snippet uses the (new-ish) Arrow function syntax, which is equivalent to the following:

```js
var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')),
    test = items.filter(function(row){
      return row.matches('tr.test');
    });
console.log(test);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="colour"></tr>
    <tr class="colour"></tr>
    <tr class="colour"></tr>
    <tr class="test"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`Element.matches()` tests the element (`Element`) against a supplied CSS selector and, if that supplied selector would match the `Element`, returns a Boolean `true`, otherwise `false`.

`Array.from()` converts the results of the Array-like collection returned from `document.querySelectorAll()` into an Array, in order to use Array methods, such as `Array.prototype.filter()`, which retains those elements in the Array for which the supplied assessment returns `true`/truthy values.

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).